# maps between indecomposable modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $M_1$,...,$M_n$ be indecomposable modules of finite length.
> Let $f_i:M_i \rightarrow M_{i+1}$ be a non bijective homomorphism of modules such that the composition map $g:=f_{n-1} \cdot\cdot\cdot f_2f_1$ is not zero.
> Assume that $\ell($im$(g))< \ell(M_i)$ $\forall1 \leq i \leq n$, where $\ell$ denotes the length of a given module.
> Let $N$ be a indecomposable direct summand of im$(g)$.

Is it true that then the map $N \rightarrow M_n$ is not bijective? If yes how can one see that?

Comment: In your assumptions, do you really want to include $n$ in the bounds for $i$? If so, you have that $\ell(im(g)) < \ell(M_n)$, so the inclusion of $N$ into $M_n$ can hardly be surjective.